# Add a method to an object after .append()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm currently creating a table where some lines can be added/deleted.

The JS part looks like this:

```
$('#absence-table').on('click', '#delete-line',function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});

$('#add-line').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#absence-table').append([
        '<tr>',
            '<td>',
                '<select name="absence-type" class="input-small">',
                    '<option value="t1">type1</option>',
                    '<option value="t2">type2</option>',
                '</select>',
            '</td>',
            '<td><input type="text" id="from" class="input-small" /></td>',
            '<td><input type="text" id="to" class="input-small" /></td>',
            '<td><div class="text-center"><input type="text" id="result" class="input-xsmall" /></div></td>',
            '<td><div class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" id="morning"></div></td>',
            '<td><div class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" id="afternoon"></div></td>',
            '<td colspan="2"><input type="text" id="comment" /></td>',
            '<td><a href="#" id="delete-line"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></td>',
        '</tr>'
    ].join(''))
});

$("#from, #to").datepicker();
```

My first problem was to make works the "click" event on the line created by the .append() function. After some search, I found that I need to use .on() and it's work.

But the datepicker on the new table line created doesn't work. How can I do?

```
$("#from, #to").datepicker(); // seems not working after .append() on the new line
```

Comment: The id (#form, #to) are used to specify a style for a single, unique element. (you can't attach events twice)

Comment: I guess that I need to use "class" instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach the `datepicker` plugin to the newly added HTML. Currently it will only be attached to elements available on load.

```
$('#add-line').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#absence-table').append(/* Super long string */)

    $("#from, #to").datepicker(); // attach to new elements
});

$("#from, #to").datepicker(); // attach on load
```

You could even DRY that up a bit by putting the `datepicker` instantiation in a function.

Comment: Oh god, this is so easy. I don't understand why I didn't think about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The date picker doesn't work because it only attaches itself to the elements with `#from` and `#to` when the page is first loaded, any new rows won't have the datepicker applied.

If you add a `to` and `from` class to those elements (because element IDs are supposed to be unique, you can do this:

```
$('#add-line').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#absence-table').append(/* Super long string */)

    // attach datepicker to new elements by targeting the last row in the table
    $("#absence-table tr:last .from, #absence-table tr:last .to").datepicker();
});

$(".from, .to").datepicker(); // attach on page load
```